# How to enforce closing bracket lint rules in python

Tags: python, indentation, lint, pylint

We're using flake8 and pylint to do our code style checks on a project.

But the problem is, none of those do any checks for how lines are split. Since consistency is nice in a project it looks really weird that we find

```
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)

foo = long_function_name(
    var_one,
    var_two,
    var_three,
    var_four)

foo = long_function_name(
    var_one,
    var_two,
    var_three,
    var_four
)

foo = {
    a,
    b}

foo = {
    a,
    b,
}
```

in our codebase. Sometimes different ways of closing a thing is right next to each other like in the example above.

Now is there a checker or a rule for pylint or flake or special checker that would just ensure:

- if you have a hanging indent, that the closing bracket, curly brackets or parentheses are always in a new line, and that we have a trailing comma above them.

Consistency is key in a clean codebase, and we can't rely on devs to stick to rules if those aren't automatically checked. So I need a checker for the cases mentioned.

Comment: Please spell-check your post title at least. Also, please read posting guidelines. There is no need to "thank" anyone for anything. In a question, "Thank you." is just noise. If your question is actually answered, then you thank them by upvoting and/or accepting an answer.

Comment: Have you heard of [black](https://github.com/python/black)? You can set it up as a pre-commit hook so that all your code is formatted the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wemake-python-styleguide`](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-python-styleguide). It is a set of `flake8` plugins with lots of new rules.

To install it run: `pip install wemake-python-styleguide`

Running: `flake8 your_module.py`

This is still just a `flake8` plugin!

The specific rule you are interested in is [`consistency.ParametersIndentationViolation`](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/violations/consistency.html#wemake_python_styleguide.violations.consistency.ParametersIndentationViolation).

Correct code samples:

```
# Correct:
def my_function(arg1, arg2, arg3) -> None:
    return None

print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

def my_function(
    arg1, arg2, arg3,
) -> None:
    return None

print(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
)

def my_function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3,
) -> None:
    return None

print(
    first_variable,
    2,
    third_value,
    4,
    5,
    last_item,
)

# Special case:

print('some text', 'description', [
    first_variable,
    second_variable,
    third_variable,
    last_item,
], end='')
```

Incorrect code samples:

```
call(1,
     2,
     3)

print(
    1, 2,
    3,
)
```

Docs: https://wemake-python-stylegui.de

Answer (score 0):

Some of the checks that PEP8 does not enforce are therefore ignored by default by [pycodestyle](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html) (which is one of the linters that [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) wraps), but they can actually be made if selected. [Here](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) you can check the error codes and change the default behaviour to select those you want to run.
Example:

```
flake8 --select E123
```

If you already have code with these styles that were not checked before, you could use [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) formatter to reformat it:

```
autopep8 --select=E123 --in-place --recursive .
```

Answer (score -1):

pylint will not do that.

List of all pylint messages 
http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

Comment: I was already suspecting that, but that's not really what I was asking. The questing is: Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm also using flake8 and wasn't able to configure it to enforce consistency in your examples, because all of your examples are PEP8 compliant.

To enforce consistency, I've found https://github.com/python/black: "The Uncompromising Code Formatter". Besides re-formatting code, it can act as a linter using the `--check` flag (see example usage below).

When I invoke black on your examples, the first three are formatted to:

```py
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two, var_three, var_four)
```

and the last two are formatted to:

```py
foo = {a, b}
```

To demonstrate: 1) how black works when line-wraps are necessary; and 2) using black as a linter:

```
$ cat bar.py
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one,
    var_two,
    var_three,
    var_four,
    var_five,
    var_six,
    var_seven)

foo = long_function_name(
    var_one,
    var_two,
    var_three,
    var_four,
    var_five,
    var_six,
    var_seven,
    var_eight,
    var_nine
)

$ black --check bar.py
would reformat bar.py
All done!   
1 file would be reformatted.

$ black bar.py
reformatted bar.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.

$ cat bar.py
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two, var_three, var_four, var_five, var_six, var_seven
)

foo = long_function_name(
    var_one,
    var_two,
    var_three,
    var_four,
    var_five,
    var_six,
    var_seven,
    var_eight,
    var_nine,
)

$ black --check bar.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file would be left unchanged.
```